# What is the Equivalent of SSIS Lookup in Kettle ( Pentaho Data Integration) or Talend

Tags: pentaho, lookup, talend, kettle

I'm looking for an equivalent of the SSIS Lookup componement in Pentaho Data Integration ( Kettle) or Talend.
A componement which take 2 sources and return no matched rows

Answer (score 0):

You can either use "[Stream lookup](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Stream+Lookup)" or "database lookup" in PDI. Just join in the two inputs and fetch the desired result.

Hope this helps :)

---

**Modifying the answer with sample code**

[image]

Consider two tables (*i have used data grid for demo purpose*): Input Table and Fact; both having field named "Name" in their tables. Now in order to find the missing rows, i do a 'Stream lookup' on these tables to find the missing data from the Fact table (*considering Fact is having lesser records than Input Table*). Finally Filter out the "**Null**" records from the stream to get the missing rows.

Check the sample gist of the above ss in [here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/f193448ba859140291a8).

[N.B.: I have used Pentaho 5.0.0 ]

Comment: Hi @Rishu ,
I have only one input ( SQL command) and one output ( Fact Table)
If want to get all row returned by the query and don't exist in Fact Table .

Comment: @SaïdAssoumani First of all please kindly edit your question with sample examples !!.. And in case of fetching the rows not exist in two tables, as i have mentioned above, you can use 'stream lookup" to fetch the missing characters and display the result.. I have edited my answer with a sample code. Check if it helps..